# How to get first n characters from variable string length in Swift

Tags: swift, string, substring

I have a string of variable length, but always containing lets say XXX at the end. How can I get the string from the start to the XXX - so without the XXX? It would be easy in python since it uses Int as string indexes, but Swift doesn't do that. How can I achieve the same result in Swift?

Python code example:

> code = "ABCDEFGXXX"

> text = code[:-3]

> so text is equal to "ABCDEFG"

Comment: `code.dropLast(3)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You should post your comment as an answer, so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Swift has full support for Unicode and uses a variety of different internal storage methods for it's String type. As a result, integer string subscripting is not supported. For your specific problem `String.dropLast(_)` is a perfect fit for your needs. Otherwise, you need to learn how to use `String.Index` and `Range` types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing python I think dropLast most resembles the python example you provided

```
code.dropLast(3)
```